# Getting GPIO pin number using devm_* api

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, gpio

I would like to get gpio pin number from one of the driver using devm_* API.

For instance, below snippet do it using "of_get_named_gpio api":

https://github.com/tanish2k09/venom_kernel_aio_otfp/blob/master/drivers/spi/spi-s3c64xx.c#L966

is there such devm_* api exist for reading gpio pin number in Linux ?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need to use GPIO numbers? Referring to GPIO by number is considered a legacy interface in the kernel. Newer code tends to use GPIO descriptors. For device resource managed allocation of GPIO descriptors, use the `devm_gpiod_get_`* functions declared by `#include <linux/gpio/consumer.h>`.

Comment: @IanAbbott, tried to use desc_to_gpio() but it gives me crash. Just wanted to see which gpio pin number is set by gpiod_set_value_cansleep().is there other interface to check it( something from /sys/..) ?

Comment: If `desc_to_gpio()` is crashing, perhaps the descriptor is invalid. Did you check it with `IS_ERR()`?

Comment: @IanAbbott, Actually same descriptor is used for  gpiod_set_value_cansleep that doesn't give me a crash, in the following lines I'm passing it to desc_to_gpio

Comment: `gpiod_set_value*()` functions are NULL and error pointer aware. So, the absence of crash doesn't mean anything here.